# Customizing the formatting of a textual property list, with multi-line text, in Python?

Tags: python, json, pretty-print, text-formatting

Consider this example, where we have an object with properties, which each contain strings - some single-line, others multi-line:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pprint

class SomeInfo(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.some_param = "Some parameter value"
    self.another_param = "Another parameter value"
    self.quite_longish_param_name = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Fusce laoreet, odio sed finibus sollicitudin,
ipsum nibh vulputate ex, quis tempor lorem enim sed
massa. Duis commodo posuere fringilla."""

some_info = SomeInfo()

formatted_prop_list_str = pprint.pformat(vars(some_info))
print(formatted_prop_list_str)
```

This prints the following in terminal:

```
{'another_param': 'Another parameter value',
 'quite_longish_param_name': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur '
                             'adipiscing\n'
                             'elit. Fusce laoreet, odio sed finibus '
                             'sollicitudin,\n'
                             'ipsum nibh vulputate ex, quis tempor lorem enim '
                             'sed\n'
                             'massa. Duis commodo posuere fringilla.',
 'some_param': 'Some parameter value'}
```

... which is close to what I want, but not quite. What I'd really want is something like this:

```
           another_param: "Another parameter value"
quite_longish_param_name: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
                           elit. Fusce laoreet, odio sed finibus sollicitudin,
                           ipsum nibh vulputate ex, quis tempor lorem enim sed
                           massa. Duis commodo posuere fringilla."
              some_param: "Some parameter value"
```

... or in other words:

- choice of quotation marks to double quotes
- no use of commas to separate parameters and their values
- multiline text has only one set of wrapping quotes; and its lines are aligned to each other, not to quotation marks; `\n` are not shown as line separators, and the multiline text is not re-wrapped
- properties' names are right-aligned, at the semicolon - and they are not wrapped in quotes.

Is there a way of persuading `pprint` to provide this kind of output - and if not, are there any other "easy" options (short of having to code my own text formatter)?

Comment: No but it looks fairly easy to write that formatting code yourself. Try it, shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Thanks @smci - then that is what I'm going to do, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval()` to convert your `str` to `dict` and then print it as per your format, like this:

```
import pprint

class SomeInfo(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.some_param = "Some parameter value"
    self.another_param = "Another parameter value"
    self.quite_longish_param_name = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Fusce laoreet, odio sed finibus sollicitudin,
ipsum nibh vulputate ex, quis tempor lorem enim sed
massa. Duis commodo posuere fringilla."""

some_info = SomeInfo()

formatted_prop_list_str = pprint.pformat(vars(some_info))
# print(type(formatted_prop_list_str))


x=eval(formatted_prop_list_str)
 
for k,v in x.items():
    print(k+': '+'\"'+v+'\"')
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
another_param: "Another parameter value"
quite_longish_param_name: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Fusce laoreet, odio sed finibus sollicitudin,
ipsum nibh vulputate ex, quis tempor lorem enim sed
massa. Duis commodo posuere fringilla."
some_param: "Some parameter value"
```

Comment: Thanks @Zeek - looks good for the most part - except for aligning the multi-line text lines to each other, and right-alignment of parameter names as semicolon.

Comment: I have been trying to align it for the past hour. Can't seem to find a way to do it in terminal. The problem is any operation I apply to align it will affect the all three lines, resulting in a weirdly formatted string. Will edit the answer if I found a way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is my function that does this kind of print:

```py
import pprint

class SomeInfo(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.some_param = "Some parameter value"
    self.another_param = "Another parameter value"
    self.quite_longish_param_name = '''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Fusce laoreet, odio sed finibus sollicitudin,
ipsum nibh vulputate ex, quis tempor lorem enim sed
massa. Duis commodo posuere fringilla.'''
    self.testlist = [5, 6, 7]

some_info = SomeInfo()

class propNameVal(object):
  def __init__(self, name, value):
    self.name = name
    self.value = value
def get_formatted_prop_list_str(inobj, indent=' ', spacer=' ', quotechar='"', propnamealign='>', sort=False):
  #print(type(sort))
  if type(sort)==list or type(sort)==tuple:
    #print("sort is list/tuple")
    propnamelist = sort
  elif sort:
    #print("sort is True")
    propnamelist = sorted( vars(inobj).keys() )
  else:
    #print("sort is False")
    propnamelist = vars(inobj).keys()
  #print(propnamelist)
  prop_names_vals = [ propNameVal(propname, vars(inobj)[propname]) for propname in propnamelist ]
  #print(prop_names_vals)
  prop_names_len = [ len(pnv.name) for pnv in prop_names_vals ]
  #print(prop_names_len)
  prop_names_maxlen = max(prop_names_len)
  #print(prop_names_maxlen)
  propnamefmt = '{:'+ propnamealign + str(prop_names_maxlen) + '}' #'{:>2}'
  prop_names_fmtd = [ propnamefmt.format(pnv.name) for pnv in prop_names_vals ]
  #print(prop_names_fmtd)
  out_lines = []
  for ip, pnv in enumerate(prop_names_vals):
    vallines = str(pnv.value).splitlines()
    if len(vallines) == 1:
      out_lines.append( '{}:{}{}{}{}'.format(prop_names_fmtd[ip], spacer, quotechar, vallines[0], quotechar) )
    else:
      for iln, valline in enumerate( vallines ):
        if iln==0:
          out_lines.append( '{}:{}{}{}'.format(prop_names_fmtd[ip], spacer, quotechar, valline) )
        elif iln==len(vallines)-1:
          tfmt = propnamefmt+' {}{}{}{}' # space instead of :
          out_lines.append( tfmt.format("", spacer, " ", valline, quotechar) )
        else:
          tfmt = propnamefmt+' {}{}{}' # space instead of :
          out_lines.append( tfmt.format("", spacer, " ", valline) )
  return "\n".join(out_lines)

formatted_prop_list_str = get_formatted_prop_list_str(some_info, sort=('another_param', 'quite_longish_param_name', 'some_param', 'testlist'))
print(formatted_prop_list_str)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 /tmp/test.py
           another_param: "Another parameter value"
quite_longish_param_name: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
                           elit. Fusce laoreet, odio sed finibus sollicitudin,
                           ipsum nibh vulputate ex, quis tempor lorem enim sed
                           massa. Duis commodo posuere fringilla."
              some_param: "Some parameter value"
                testlist: "[5, 6, 7]"
```